# Trying to configure CentOS 6 and PHP 5.3.15

Tags: centos, yum, repository, php53

I'm trying to replicate a production environment so It's very important that I run PHP 5.3.15.  The problem is that my dev server is running Centos 6 and the package manager will only install PHP 5.3.3.  I've read that Centos 6 is forever tied to PHP 5.3.3 and upgrading is discouraged.  Is this true?  I've tried to install the PHP 5.3.15 rpm directly but it fails due to dependency issues:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by php-common-5.3.15-1.w5.x86_64
    libcurl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by php-common-5.3.15-1.w5.x86_64
    libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by php-common-5.3.15-1.w5.x86_64
```

Should I consider a different Linux distro for my dev environment?  I'm newish to all of this so really appreciate someone who can clear this up for me.

Comment: If you try to replicate a production environment, why don't you use the exact same OS? BTW, there are other repositories available for CentOS, but they all start at 5.3.18, not 5.3.13 (see http://pkgs.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install a package built for CentOS 5 on CentOS 6.  If you're trying to replicate the production environment, you should be using the same OS that production is using as well.

After a quick search using the package name above, it looks like the package was originally grabbed from the [Webtatic Yum Repo](http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/).  From that post, there are links at the bottom of the page for [running 5.3 on RHEL/CentOS 5](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) and [running 5.4 on RHEL/CentOS 6](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php54/).

In short: you should be using the same distro *and* version/release that production is using if you're trying to replicate the environment.